# Resources For Calculating Average Sentence Length

Tags: calculations, latex-misc

I'm writing my masters thesis and my supervisor has picked up my sentence structure, in that they are too long. She commented that Microsoft Word has a feature to investigate 'large' sentences. How can I do this with TeX? I'm using a mac and TexShop.

Comment: Not a very TeXy way: copy and paste the text from the generated pdf file to Word.

Comment: Or if you don't have Word: there are [tools to count the number of words in a tex file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document). To count sentences, we'll just count the number of periods (unless you use a lot of commands/math with the character, you shouldn't need to strip the tex file) `cat file.tex | sed 's/[^.]//g' | wc -c` should give you a number that is one more than the total number of period marks used.

Comment: Willie Wong: comment should be an answer!

Answer (score 9):

I think this is the easiest way.  First, make sure you have [pdftotext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext) and [diction](http://www.gnu.org/software/diction/diction.html) installed.  These should be available via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

1. Render your document to a PDF.  Let's assume it's called `paper.pdf`.
2. Grab the plain text from the PDF using `pdftotext`.  At the terminal, run this: `pdftotext paper.pdf paper.txt`
3. Now run `style -l N paper.txt`, where you should replace `N` with a number.  This will print out all lines of your document that are longer than `N` words.

Alternatively, you can do it all as a one-liner:

```
$ pdflatex paper.tex && pdftotext paper.pdf - | style -l 20
```

`style` is extremely powerful and has many other features.  For a good overview, see [here](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/56833).

Comment: One could alternatively use DeTeX instead of `pdftotext` to get a plain text version to send to `style`.  I find, however, that pdftotext works a lot better, especially if one has a lot of markup in his or her document that DeTeX doesn't understand (e.g., TikZ).  pdftotext also works a lot better if one splits one's original document up into multiple .tex files that one \include{}'s.

Comment: using `style` without any parameters will give you a summary that will tell you the % of long ("at least 27 word") sentences.

Comment: @ESultanik, do you know how to tell diction/style that abbreviations are not (usually) ends of sentences? (Dr., Fig., etc.)

Comment: @Geoff This should work for most cases (except for 'etc.', but it's easy to extend the regex for those special cases):
pdftotext paper.pdf - | sed 's/\([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\)\./\1/g' | ...

Comment: @ESultanik. Just drop the period, okay. It seems to me that style should support this.