# Counting words in a Latex document

Tags: word-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document)

is there any way to count the words in Latex?I don't want to count it from my pdf but straight away from my main code....Thank you very much

Comment: Hi Vangelis, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). On the face of it, your question looks quite a lot like [is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document?rq=1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document?rq=1). If this is the case, please let us know so that we can close it as a duplicate :) Welcome to the group!

Comment: thanks!Hoe the LaTeX Word Counter works,I run the application I choose the file I press count but nothing is happening!

Answer (score 2):

[TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/index.html) might be of some help to you. Also look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7746/is-there-a-simple-way-to-obtain-the-statistic-data-of-the-document-being-typeset).

Comment: I am using windows 7,is that possible?I need a separate program if there exists something like that, and not to use commands to my main latex text?Is there anything useful that you can suggest?

Comment: @Vangelis -- `texcount` will work under windows as long as you have `perl` installed (e.g., ActivePerl).  See the [FAQ](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html).

Comment: I have downloaded the activeperl but I can't understand how I will connect it with textcount, can anybody help me? in the FAQ section I can't understand what I have to do