# How do you count number of word occurrences?

Tags: word-count

How do you count the number of word occurrences in your tex files? The reason I do this is to easier recognize words I use too much in a text. At the moment I use the following one-liner in the bash.

```
cat *.tex | sed 's/[[:space:]|[:punct:]]\+/\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

What it does is, output all .tex-Files with `cat`, substitute the whitespaces and punctuations with a line-break using `sed`, `sort` the output, count the unique words and `sort` it again after the number output by `uniq -c`.

One of the problems I have with that approach is, that words that belong together but are divided by a whitespace are counted separately. So for example "New York" you get k occurrences of New and n occurrences of York, mixing with other occurrences of New and York.

**EDIT:** Another problem is of course, how do you recognize word inflection such as declension and conjugation? But that's probably something way out of scope of a one-liner, or does anyone have an idea how to cope with that?

**EDIT2:** As Hendrik and Joseph pointed out, that's not really TeX-related, but perhaps somebody finds it useful :)

Comment: I think your question isn't really TeX related, so I'm voting to close it as "off-topic". My point is somehow that a satisfactory answer wouldn't involve any TeX knowledge but rather access to a huge database.

Comment: I'd agree that the question _as posed_ does not really seem to be TeX-related. I'd vote to close if I were not a moderator.

Comment: Alternatively, look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/ for a TeX-specific set of answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, you're probably right that it's not only related to TeX but text-processing as a whole. I've thought that maybe other people had the same issue when writing their thesis in TeX, so I just asked.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot say much about the run latex, and then use `dvi2tty` on the output `.dvi` file. This would take better care of macro expansion. I suggest therefore:

```
dvi2tty 00.dvi | sed  's/[[:space:]|[:punct:]|[:digit:]]\+/\n/g' | sed '/^$/d' | tr "A-Z" "a-z" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed "/ 1 /d"
```

which is similar to your pipe, except that

- It treats digits as separators.
- It ignores spaces
- It eliminates empty lines
- It eliminates words that occur only once.