# Count words and spaces

Tags: word-count

I search for a package or a script, that can count the number of characters including spaces in my document. I have tried to search for it, and I have found many solutions, that should do this, but I can't get it to work. I'm using Miktex and Texmaker.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\input{A_File} % This is a file that can contain everything, eq. figures, equations, minpages etc. To make it simple , let 's say that it contains the following text and equation
This is an example
\begin{equation}
2+2=4 \text{A text}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

So the file `A_File` contains 'This is an example' and 'A text' which should be counted. I now want to count the the number of characters with spaces in my document. As it can be seen there are 4 characters in 'This', 2 in 'is', 2 in 'an', 7 in 'example' and 3 spaces. Furthermore there are 5 characters in ' A text' with 1 space. This gives 24 number of characters including spaces.

The script should then display:

Total number of characters including spaces = 24.

I'm not so good at latex, so I just want a script I can copy and insert, and then it works.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's `texcount`, an external (perl?) script. It's easy to run it under Linux/MacOS, but windows?

Comment: I use windows. How does this 'perl' works. Is it something in Texmaker ? Can you perhaps give an minimal example of the use ?

Comment: `perl` is a powerful scripting language and the perl binaries must be installed of course to run other perl scripts. I don't know whether `texcount` is shipped with MikTeX at all, I don't use that stuff

Comment: Have you seen this question: [How to count all characters including spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48498/4778)

Comment: Maybe related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document

Comment: TeXcount may be asked to count the number of word or characters, but not including spaces. Count spaces in LaTeX source is rather problematic. How many spaces are in "`x<space><space><space><space><space>x`" ? One or five? And how many spaces are  "`x\hspace{5em}x`"? And how to now if the space in  "`this<space>space`" will be  lost in the pdf, due to a linebreak?

Comment: @Fran IMHO a space is (a space) inter-words even if more then (well one space). here (x       x) one space.

Comment: @touhami In word processors you type 5 spaces and you get 5 (or more) spaces (equivalent to `\space\space\space\space\space`). In a LaTeX with the same 5 spaces you get 1 `\space` (or more). If the final space printed is what matter, how we should consider superfluous spaces, `\quad` or other  [spacing commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing)?  How count the extra space added/  removed to justify the margins and break lines in LateX, Word or whatever?  ... If that do not matter,  why on earth do the counting?

Comment: How should `This is a unique function $f$ such that $blah math$ holds` be counted? Also, do you want a nondestructive way to do this? As in, should it also produce a pdf that contains the normal output from compiling the file? Or are you okay with it only producing a word count?

Comment: @Fran IMHO a space is blanck betwen two words (if it's one or five or `\quad` or `\hfill`, it's one) my idea is if in a paragraph we count 100 words there is 99 space. but may be it's not so easy.

Comment: #Alenanno #Rico

Yes, I have seen all those solutions, but I can't get them to work. I espacially like this perl thing, but it doesn't work for me. Can you perhaps give a more detail explanation how to get the perl script working ?

Comment: @touhami To make a pure TeX solution to this, it would be necessary to make the catcode of space into "other", and then the easiest thing to do would be to count all spaces. To count only relevant spaces, I would set up a two-state state machine that shifts to state "space" when it sees a space, and in state space doesn't count further space characters.

Comment: @Morten: You don't need Perl to run TexCount, you can use the webinterface:
http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php
Simply paste your tex code or upload the entire *.tex file.
Again, it does not count spaces, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Without counting spaces, probably TeXcount is the best solution. Otherwise, assuming that additional normal spaces characters in the source code can be safely ignored (but not space commands as `\quad`, including even `\\` and `\par` ...) one solution that could work reasonably *for simple documents* (not for child documents and text in math mode, sorry) is convert from `.tex` to `.lyx` using:

- LyX menu : <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>ImportFile</kbd> > <kbd>LaTeX (plain) ...</kbd>
- `tex2lyx` directly (e.g, at the system prompt type `tex2lyx -c report  test.tex test.lyx`, and next `lyx test.lyx`).

Then, simply ask for the statistics in LyX  <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Statitistics...</kbd>

**Example:**

Source code `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
This is an example.
This is a file that can contain everything, eq. figures, equations, minpages etc. To make it simple , let 's say that it contains the following text and equation
\begin{equation}
2+2=4 \text{A text}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: mwe]