# Number of lines in double spacing (compared to Word)

Tags: formatting, line-spacing, msword, setspace

I am a newbie to LaTeX. I noticed that my document is almost a page longer in Word compared to LaTeX. (~7.25 in latex, ~8.25 in Word). This seems to be because my Word document has 23 lines per page, where my LaTeX document has 27. I *think* the margins are the same (I set them to be, but haven't measured them).

The beginning of my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

...and that's pretty much all the formatting I have.

Is the default "double spacing" in LaTeX/`setspace` smaller than Word? How can I manually adjust this (in LaTeX)?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82914/14100

Comment: Best not to adjust, as it will produce an inferior document. Consider the better typography and help save the environment by saving on paper. If you still want to have similarity use the geometry package.

Comment: I'm in the US, and Word uses margins in inches here. I don't think a 1.25in side margin looks so bad (compared to default 1in). The double spacing in Word does look bad, and I won't be using it. This is primarily for my own edification.

Comment: related, possibly a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean. Besides, the difference in the number of pages may also come from different fonts, different hyphenation (LaTeX seems to be more efficient), different kerning ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is (mainly) because the `\doublespacing` that is the  equivalent to `\setstretch{1.667}` is not the exact equivalent to the  double lines in Word.

To reduce 27 to 23 lines you can use:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}
```

Or simpler:

```
\linespread{2} % without any package.
```

Same effect:

```
\baselineskip=29pt %in the body of the document
```

With `lineno` you can test quickly this settings:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\linespread{2} 
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```