# Double or one-half spacing

Tags: line-spacing

How do I double space just a portion of a document, and not the entire thing?

How do I double space an entire document?  What package should I use?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\usepackage{setspace}` will help.

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/819/double-line-spacing

Answer (score 12):

> How do I double space an entire document? What package should I use?

As commented, one option is to use the package `setspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
One line\par 
Another line
\end{document}
```

But note that `\doublespacing` is not equivalent to the double spacing in Word. I explained some alternatives to obtain that in  [Number of lines in double spacing (compared to Word)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84260/number-of-lines-in-double-spacing-compared-to-word).

> How do I double space just a portion of a document, and not the entire
>   thing?

The easier option to limit the double spacing effect is also the package `setspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
One line\par 
Another line\par
\begin{doublespace}
One line\par 
Another line
\end{doublespace}
One line\par 
Another line
\end{document}
```

If you need a Word-like double spacing for some paragraphs use:

```
\begin{spacing}{2}
.......
\end{spacing}
```

Another option without packages could be change the  `\baselineskip` inside a minipage:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \baselineskip=2\baselineskip
     .....
\end{minipage}
```

Or simply change the  `\baselineskip` in the main text two times:

```
\baselineskip=2\baselineskip % start double spacing
.......
\baselineskip=.5\baselineskip % start single  spacing
```