# How do I change my LaTex document to follow some Word requirements?

Tags: fonts, spacing, margins, line-spacing, dimensions

I am writing my thesis in LaTex and I am strictly required to write:

1. With Times New Roman
2. 12 pt (which I have read 12pt in Word is different from 12pt in LaTex)
3. One and a half line spacing
4. All the four margins (left, right, up and down) need to be of 2.5 cm

Can you help me with these four commands to add to my thesis?

Comment: At my university, they had their own .sty file that I had to use. Does that exist for your university?

Answer (score 14):

> With Times New Roman

With `xelatex` or `lualatex` you can use any .ttf or .otf font available in your system, and of course times. For `pdflatex` or any other compiler there are also an obsolete `times` package, that should be replaced by the [`math­ptmx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) pack­age, which sup­ports Times Ro­man text.

> 12 pt  (which I have read 12pt in Word is different from 12pt in LaTex)

Hardly anyone will notice this, but this is a duplicate of [Setting a document in MS Word-12pt (12bp)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp)

> One and a half line spacing

... that is also different of Word spacing, but this is also a duplicate of [Double or one-half spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196967/double-or-one-half-spacing)

> All the four margins (left, right, up and down) need to be of 2.5 cm

Easy way:

```
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: These days I think `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` are the replacement for `mathptmx`.