# set font size and line spacing

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I need a font size of 12 pt and a line spacing of 1.5 lines.

I try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5} %regulate line spacing
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12pt}{0}\selectfont} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[0]
\end{document}
```

I set the baseline skip in the second `{}` in `\fontsize` to 0 pt because I think it would interfere with `\linespread`. On the other hand `\linespread` appears not to work.

Can you help?

Comment: Why don't you use `\usepackage{setspace}` with `\onehalfspacing`? (and leave the font tampering aside, supplying it to the documentclass as an option).

Comment: As to the use of linespread, you should take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/105447.

Comment: `\fontsize{12pt}{0}` specifies 12pt font on 0pt !!! baseline, so  stretching the baseline by a factor of 1.5 doesn't do much.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, if I want line spacing to be be exact 1.5 should I provide `\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}`? Do I need to include the factor 1.2? I want to benchmark the result to Microsoft Word.

Comment: You mean you'd like to use this to benchmark MS Word's results, wright?  ;-)

Comment: you want a linespace bigger than latex's default so why are you setting it to smaller values (impossibly small) in the case of 0pt.  presumably you want a 12bp font on an 18bp baseline if that;s what they mean by 1.5 linespace so `\fontsize{12bp}{18bp}`  your code has a baseline space of `0*1.5=0pt` so tex doesn't even try to maintain a regular baseline at all as it has impossible constraints

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I thought `\baselineskip` is additive - on top of the `\baselineskip` and additional `\linespread` would be added.

Comment: no you are multiplying 0 by 1.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Useless and counterproductive messing with `\fontsize`. This simpler MWE work as expected:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

There a 12pt font and a 1.5 line spacing. What more?

Comment: For 1.5 line spacing with 12pt font, you should use `\linespread{1.241}` (that's what `setspace` does). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/105447

Comment: @gusbrs I disagree. [I know that setspace have other thoughts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84268/11604) of what is a "double" or "one-half" line, but most people is the number of lines reduced by a factor of 2 or 1.5. At this respect linespread does a good job: with a `\lipsum[1-4]` of 12pt you will have by default 37 lines in first page but only 7 lines less with `\linespread{1.241}`  (37/30= 1.23 ~1.25) so a factor of 1.24 is really  more a "onequarterspacing" whereas `\linespread{1.5}` change from 37 to 25 lines (37/25 =1.48 ~ 1.5).

Answer (score 7):

The supplied code specifies a 12pt font on a 0pt baseline, the `\linespread` multiplies the requested baseline spacing by 1.5, but that is still 0pt.

unless you set `\lineskiplimit` to a negative value TeX does not try to honour a 0pt `\baselineskip` (which would cause every line of a paragraph to overprint in the same vertical position). It just stacks the lines separated by `\lineskip` space (1pt by default) so there is no even spacing, lines with capitals or accents take more space than those without.

It is not at all well defined what you mean by "a font size of 12 pt and a line spacing of 1.5 lines" but I would guess that you mean 12bp font on an 1.5*12bp=18bp baseline so perhaps  `\fontsize{12bp}{18bp}\selectfont` is what you are looking for. But it is almost certainly better to not use explicit numbers at all and use the `setspace` package and one of its preset spacing commands.

Answer (score 5):

Another traditional solution for the purpose:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would be the general command for line spacing with `setspace`, e.g. a line spacing of 1.2 lines?

Comment: @Viesturs Besides `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing`, and `\doublespacing`, `setspace` has `\setstretch{baselinestretch}` if a different spacing is required.

Comment: So, I would call \setstretch{1.2}?

Comment: @Viesturs Yes, that would be it.

Answer (score 0):

For a 24pt line height, change the line to \fontsize{12pt}{24pt} and add a \par line at the end of the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5} %regulate line spacing
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12pt}{24pt}\selectfont} 
\begin{document}
\lipsum[0]\par 
\end{document}
```