# text layout 12pt? interline 1.5 texmaker

Tags: line-spacing, layout

I'm doing a report and in the word should result in the text 12 and interline 1,5 but I'm not sure that 12 pt in latex is actually the same.

For the interline I'm using this

```
\onehalfspacing %interline%
\linespread{1.4}
```

Thanks you in advance for the answer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84268/11604

Comment: Thank you but i don't need double I need 1,5

Comment: What you are doing in your code is first set the interline to 1.241 (but only if you are using really a 12pt font size) and then change it to 1.4. The link show you that the  interline of 2 in Word is  equivalent to 1.667 in LaTeX, and therefore 1.5 in Word is not exactly 1.241  nor 1.4 in LaTeX but  ... (please complete the phrase).