# Changing default line spacing in Latex document

Tags: document-classes

How do I change (increase) the line spacing in the entire Latex document? I'm guessing it's an option on the documentclass but I couldn't find a reference.

Comment: Which documentclass are you using?

Comment: In the classes I know of, there does no such option exist.  Usually you have to engage another package such as `setspace` with its commands `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84268/11604

Comment: Thanks everyone. @Fran, that link was very helpful - thanks.. Seems \linespread{n} is native, does what I wanted, and does not require a new package. If you would like to post that as the answer I can close the question.

Comment: @TonyK  If the issue is well solved in another answered question is  better  close it as duplicate to avoid scatter solutions to similar questions, making it harder to others to find the useful answers.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure of the protocol.