# how to define vertical spacing between lines inside paragraph, and vertical spacing between paragraphs throughout the document

Tags: spacing

how to define verticle spacing between lines inside paragraph, and vertical spacing between paragraphs throughout the document? I know that parskip seems to address the vertical spacing between paragraphs, but i couldn't find where to define the spacing between lines inside the paragraph that doesn't screw the parskip definition.

Comment: Before looking for complicated solutions, could the `setspace` package be a solution for you? I won't allow fine-tuning, but it gives standard options in typography (one half spacing, double spacing…)

Comment: To change vertical spacing between paragraphs set a glue held in `\parskip` e.g. `\setlength\parskip{12pt plus 3pt minus 6pt}`

Comment: There are a few ways to set the interline space (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84268/11604)). For paragraphs  skips is just set `\parskip` as Celdor saud, but this can produce unexpected skips in toc, list and headers, so it can be better use the package parskip anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The `\baselineskip` is TeX primitive register which controls the vertical spaces between lines. Its type is "skip" but you can set only basic dimension which gives the distance from baseline to baseline. If the `\baselineskip` is too small (the lines are overlap for instance), then the `\baselineskip` is not used but `\lineskip` value directly between bottom of the first line and top of the second is used. What is used is controlled by `\lineskiplimit` TeX primitive register. More exactly: TeX tries to keep distance between base-lines by `\baselineskip` value first but if such a result has the direct distance (between bottom of first line and top of the second) less than `\lineskiplimit` then `\baselineskip` value is not used but direct distance is set by `\lineskip` value. The lines can overlap if you set negative `\lineskiplimit`.

`\parskip` value is added between paragraphs to the space calculated form `\baselineskip` or `\lineskip`.

Plain TeX default setting is

```
\baselineskip=12pt
\lineskiplimit=0pt
\lineskip=1pt
\parskip=0pt plus1pt
```