# Word count excluding certain environments

Tags: environments, sourcecode, pseudocode, word-count

I would like a way to get a word count while ignoring certain environments. The reason for this is that I have quite a bit of pseudocode enclosed within multiple verbatim blocks.

Ideally, a solution would be like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989807/1054899), but with the ability to select which environments to not select.

edit: I am using TexStudio

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no solution you want.

You can try to use package [`ifthen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen). Define a boolean variable (`\newboolean{WordCount}`), set it to true (`\setboolean{WordCount}{true}`) or false (`\setboolean{WordCount}{false}`) and suround all environments you do not wanted to be counted with `\ìfthenelse{WordCount}{}{<your environment>}`. So if `WordCount` is `false` your environment is executed, if it is `true` your environment is not executed:

```
%in your praeambel:
\usepackage{ifthen}  % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen
\newboolean{WordCount}
\setboolean{WordCount}{true}
%\setboolean{WordCount}{false}
...
%in your document:
\ifthenelse{\boolean{WordCount}}{% 
   % True, no environment to be executed
}{% False, execute environment:
 <your environment here>
}
```

Please take a look to the [related question is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document) and combine one of the methods there with the code above.

Hope that helps.