# Word count several files in LyX

Tags: lyx, include, word-count

I want to perform a word count on my LyX document. The problem is that I include several files within my main document

- main.lyx

  - include file1.lyx
  - include file2.lyx

    - include file21.lyx
  - include file3.lyx

I have not figured out how to do a proper PDF wordcount, since the results vary depending on how I export the PDF, but I know I could do a `Tools -> Statistics... -> count words` and add them up for each file, but I have something like 20 documents, hence this will be unnecessary time consuming work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export to text and use `wc`.

For example, if you are in the Italian manuals directory, you get the following output:

```
$ lyx -e text *.lyx && wc -w *.txt
starting local cmake binary
 18958 Customization.txt
  4115 Intro.txt
 11047 Tutorial.txt
 34402 UserGuide.txt
 68522 total
```

If you want just the total:

```
$ lyx -e text *.lyx && wc -w *.txt | awk '{ print $1 }' | tail -n 1
68522
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you also know how to do this in Windows? I forgot to mention that is the OS I am working in.

Comment: Cygwin or Python should work. The same idea holds. Export to text and use any kind of word count program.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen Note that in general it is difficult to get an accurate word count. Using this method, a *empty* 5x5 table where all line are drawn will be count as *37 words*!! More ideas on how to count (after exporting `.lyx` to `.tex`) can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536).