# Extracting number of words from document with equations

Tags: word-count, latex-to-word

I wonder if there is a systematic way to extract the number of words from a LaTeX document in which there are also mathematical equations. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Check http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536/9823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would I do?

Word counting is hard when you have equations, and I assume that you want to do this because a journal is asking for a certain size of your article... but, be careful! Usually journals count equations as word! (The equivalence is given by the horizontal space carried by the equation typesetting), and figures too.

In Linux there is a tool called `wc`, stand for "word count", if you type in the terminal

> wc -c your_file_name.tex

It will return the number of characters in the file, I would say that the mean length of an English word is 5 characters, so you will have an estimate.

However, if you wnat to go further, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989807/177729) or [this!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536/9823)