# Wordcounter package in LaTeX?

Tags: word-count

I have found [a lot of suggestions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document), mentioning programs and other form of software excluding a direct package in LaTeX. Do you have to use the PDF-word counter or another program to count words?

Isn't it possible to tell the amoung of words like by using a package? For example "usepackage{wordcounter}" and "begin{count} (...) end{count}"? It would be more easily for me using an package and command in LaTeX to count words, than using a program outside the LaTeX world. If I for example have to correct my document, and I have to do it a lot, it takes a lot of time to copy my text into another program. It would be easier, if I just had to compile the correct text twice - and than have the correct among of words.

So is there those kind of package? Or a smart method to count words?

Comment: You should have a look at [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54630/34551](that answer) that gives a hack to implement that in LaTex. But, as [this is written in that answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54680/34551), the general answer seems to be "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already some links and a good answer by Clément available, so I can just supplement it.

I vaguely recall seeing a long time ago a LaTeX package that aimed to do this, but as I recall it was very fragile and wouldn't work on my document.

Most word counting scripts will process the tex files directly, so no copy-pasting is required. However, they will have to be run separately.

An option, as has already been explained in the [previously posted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117532/17644) referred to by Clément, you may be able to run the word count script from the TeX document and import the result. To do this using [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/index.html), there are explanations in the FAQ on [how to run TeXcount from your TeX code](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#latexcall), and [how to include the result in the typeset document](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#includecount). This should get the word count included into your document every time you typeset.