# Template Trouble

Tags: fonts, bibtex, header-footer, line-spacing, word-count

*Following code*

```
%Nam scripta a cursus ad philosophíæ scientiae

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=5cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{lastpage}

%Header/Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Name \\
Institute \\
University, Country \\
Study Number \\
\Email
}
\rhead{Date: from \\ to}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

*Instructions from Professor*

My professor is very stringent when it comes to "how everything have to look like".

- no front page
- font size 12pt
- traditional font type (e.g. Times or Platino)
- line spacing 1.5
- left margin 2cm, right margin 5cm
- use page # of ##
- personal information in header
- word count at the top of the document (excluding information in header, footer and references)
- references (book): AUTHOR, YEAR, TITLE (in italics), PLACE of publication: PUBLISHER
- references (journal article): AUTHOR, YEAR, TITLE (in quotation marks), JOURNAL name, VOLUME, PAGE
  numbers

*Code Problems*

Problems with my code: placing the header correctly and getting a footer with "page # of ##".

I don't know how to: use a traditional font type, define the line space, make a word count at the top of the document and how to make bibtex to use this specific references.

A last wish: I would like to have a centered title on page one and two (onecolumn) and beneath each title the twocolumn text.

---

Hopefully you can help me.
Thank you very much in advance.
Yours faithfully,
Fröhlich

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are asking a lot of questions ;-) The footer is easy

Comment: The header is too small for all those information you want to provide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet finished, but done so far are

- Times --> `\usepackage{mathptmx}`
- Footer with the page progress --> clear the fields with `\fancyhf{}` first, otherwise it's messed up.
- `\twocolumn` stuff for the first two pages
- Somehow correct name header

### I have no clue for the desired reference and word count (at the moment)

```
%Nam scripta a cursus ad philosophíæ scientiae

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=5cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,head=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\onehalfspacing
\parindent0pt

%Header/Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lhead{Ann Elk -- Ministry of Silly Walks \\
Cambridge, Great Britain -- Study 1 \\
ann.elk@mosw.uk
}
\rhead{Date: from 1969\\ to 1974\\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No head line
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% First title

\twocolumn[\centering \large \bfseries The Theory on Brontosaurs]
\blindtext[3]

\clearpage
\twocolumn[\centering \large \bfseries The extended theory on Brontosaurs]
\blindtext[3]
\clearpage

\onecolumn

\blindtext[20]


\cite{Lam94}
% Not the correct style
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}            % Is found usually, it's a standard demo bib always included in TeX distribution

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed a way to count words if you're using XeLaTeX [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=20289). "...even words within expanded macros are counted, a hyphenated word is counted as one.". Maybe that can help?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer (vielen Dank) thank you so far! But let me be honest, you don't look like an Ann Elk ;-) ... I don't close the my question yet, because I hope that you or anyone else have the abilities to help me with the last questions ;-)

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich: I think, they are solvable. Ann Elk is my way of making jokes here (although I take your question as serious)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I guessed it ;-) ... Monthy Python, right? :D

Comment: Possibly helpful re. word count: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117532/. @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich Generally, the site likes to have one question per... well, per question. It makes it easier for people to find solutions and easier for people to answer. Suppose another user posts an answer to the outstanding queries. Whose answer will you accept in that case?

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich: Right ;-)

Comment: @cfr: I'll have a look tonight -- I am on long meeting today, without chance to improve anything.