# Count Characters without Spaces

Tags: spacing, texmaker, characters, count

I'm writing my BSc thesis right now in LaTeX using texmaker. The maximum amount of characters (without spaces) for the thesis is 70'000. Is there a decent way to count this? Copy-pasting it into Word is quite tedious and sometimes several words are pasted without any spaces and so on. So it's not really precise...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: count one page and multiply with the number of pages.  That's always accurate according to percusse's **Law of nonsensical thesis requirements**

Comment: I'll ask my supervisor what he thinks about the rule... :P

Comment: Who do you think will count your characters if you don't ?

Comment: [Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document)