# Installing wordcount

Tags: installing, word-count

I need to count words in a paper. The journal I am writing for suggests to use `wordcount.tex` (and the related `wordcount.sh`). I am using TeX Live on a Mac and I could not find these files; I found them on the CTAN.

Now my question is: how should I install these files? Or where should I place them within the TeX Directory Structure?

Comment: Did you tried what's in the manual? Have a look at http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/faq.html#setup

Comment: I am considering wordcount, not TeXCount!

Answer (score 1):

Download the package at from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/wordcount) ([direct download link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wordcount.zip)), unpack it, extract its contents (`wordcount.tex` and `wordcount.sh`) and copy it in the same folder as your document. Let's assume this document is name `test.tex`, and that it is in the folder `/home/work/`.

Launch a console, go to `/home/work/` using the command `cd`, i.e., do

```
cd /home/work/
```

Then give to your script `wordcount.sh` the right to be executed:

```
chmod +x wordcount.sh
```

You have to do all of the above only once. Once all of this is set up, a simple

```
./wordcount.sh test.tex
```

should gives you what you want. Make sure that you can compile your document `test.tex` without errors,  otherwise `wordcount.sh` might not work.

If you are confused by Mac's terminal or uneasy with it, you could ask at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or try apple support.

You might also want to compare `wordcount`'s output with other software's count. For this, have a look at [Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534/34551)

Comment: Yes, this is what has been suggested by the help desk of the journal. But I wonder whether I can place the files in some general folder in order to use them with any document.