# Subtitle command for amsart document class (not using \\)

Tags: titles, amsart

I have a research report I have to write in `LaTeX` for uni, and because you obviously can't really have a word limit with `LaTeX`, we have a page limit and have been given a strict template we have to use. Therefore I am not allowed to change the document class (or the margin width, font size etc...).

Ideally, I really want a subtitle, but the `amsart` document class - which is the one we must use - does not have one. Although the `\\` command within `\title{}` gives the desired effect on the title page of my report, the `amsart` document class also reprints the title of your report in the top margin of **every** odd page (as well as the author in the top margin of every even page), and unfortunately it does not seem to 'read' the `\\` command in this case and the title runs off the page.

I would like to have it so that only the title is reprinted in the top margins, and so that the subtitle only appears on the title page i.e. basically I just need some form of `\subtitle` command without changing the document class.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Edit: I've tried to add a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

![1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7YjP.png

Comment: "because you obviously can't really have a word limit with LaTeX" - [citation needed](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-correct-word-count-of-a-latex-document

Comment: Hi Au101, while I appreciate there may be a way of doing a word count on LaTeX, the report is for a fourth year maths course, and so the problem arises when you try to say 'how many words is this really long equation?'

Comment: Ah good point usually equations are not included in word counts in my experience, but obviously that's little use to you -- and so is the existence of word count tools anyway, since it's not you who sets the requirements but your instructor, however, you and others reading might benefit from knowing about them in the future and it's something you might be able to mention to your instructor

Comment: Yes unfortunately my paper is 80% equations! Thank you - it is definitely useful.

Comment: How exactly does that work? Can't help but feel that would violate the conditions I have to adhere to when writing this report. It's basically my dissertation for my Masters, so the formatting rules are pretty damn strict. We are only allowed to use 'standard, commonly used formatting commands', and any extra formatting to commands have to be checked with our supervisor first :/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice problem! `;-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a command that temporarily prints its argument (for `\maketitle`) and then redefine it gobble it.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\DeclareRobustCommand{\subtitle}[1]{\\#1}

\begin{document}

\title{A big title\subtitle{with a subtitle}}
\author{Grace}

\maketitle
\renewcommand{\subtitle}[1]{}

\kant[1-12]

\end{document}
```

### Page 1

[image]

### Page 3

[image]

Alternatively, use the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\title[A big title]{A big title\\with a subtitle}
\author{Grace}

\maketitle

\kant[1-12]

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: This is perfect thank you - I have gone for the second option. Thanks again!!