# Amount of words in latex book, article?

Tags: tools, latextools

running `wc -w` against latex files does not amswer question of actual words of content in article, book. Therefore, how to count them?

Comment: Have a look on the `texcount` utitily. It is usually installed with TL

Comment: See [Is there any way to do a correct word count of a LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534/110998). The answers are already 6 years old, but some might still be useful.