# Why is there such a huge discrepancy between the Overleaf and Microsoft Office Word word counter

Tags: msword, overleaf, word-count

I've just finished my dissertation, which I chose to write using a template on Overleaf (the LaTeX template editor).

My word count on Overleaf was about 18,000. I thought I would C&P into Word and it came up as 21,500. Obviously a huge dilemma, since my word limit is 20,000.

Is there anything people know about Overleaf that could account for the difference in word count? I was thinking maybe the preface/abstract/appendix isn't included in the word count, but then I am sure this wouldn't fill the difference.

Comment: What did you copy into MS Word? The TeX component or the PDF text? If it is the first you might encounter TeX macros treated as own words, if the second maybe the wrong interpretation of some characters (like ligatures).

Comment: That's unlikely, there are a few sections with lots of maths. Presumably Overleaf doesn't count these, but could Word be counting each symbol as one word? There definitely isn't enough equations to account for the difference by themselves.

Comment: So I assume you copy the TeX code?! Concerning math: I do not know how Overleaf counts that, but you could test this with a simple document. Here are some further things which Word might count as words: environments (figure, table), tabular delimiters, TeX macros (like `\par`), ...

Comment: Counting words is quite a complex topic, different tools giving different results is to be expected, in my experience (which, of course, doesn't help you with your dilemma, I'll admit).
Overleaf seems to use `texcount` to count its words: https://www.overleaf.com/help/85#.V10GGVV_eV4 I would recommend looking at how `texcount` counts words, and seeing if you can find any information about how Word counts words (or if Word can be configured -- I haven't used it in years, so I don't know). Maybe that can tell you where the discrepancy comes from.

Comment: word counting is mostly just nonsense to satisfy arbitrary thesis requirements. How many words are in `The matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}$` ? The answer is some number between 2 and 9 depending what and how you count. If you take that amount of variability and apply to a whole document the result is rarely meaningful.

Comment: Following from David's comment see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534 which describes how  professional publishers do it.

Comment: Just a thought - could the difference be in whether automatically created content such as tables of content and bibliography is counted?

Answer (score 7):

(I'm co-founder at Overleaf.) As alpenwasser indicates in a comment, Overleaf uses `texcount` to count the words. You can find out more here: https://www.overleaf.com/help/85.

At the time of writing, we run `texcount` with the options `-quiet -merge -incbib -dir -sub=none -utf8 -sum`.

A way of customising the `texcount` options on Overleaf is on our roadmap. In the meantime, if you'd like to try out other options, you can run texcount locally or use the handy web interface, if your text is easily copy-and-paste-able: http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php