# Generating LaTeX Wordcount As a Variable?

Tags: overleaf, word-count

I'm writing an article for the American Geophysical Union, and they have an absurd method of quantifying length:

> For most journals, Research Articles are allowed to be up to 25
> publication units (PU), where 1 PU is 500 words or 1 display element
> (figure or table). The title, authors, affiliations, key points,
> keywords, text in tables (but not captions) and references are
> excluded from word counts. Longer papers are assessed an excess length
> fee. Research Letters for Geophysical Research Letters have a maximum
> length of 12 publication units. Longer papers are not considered in
> GRL and will be returned for shortening. For most journals,
> Commentaries are limited to 6 publication units (recommended length is
> about 2000 words and 1-2 figures).

I'm working on writing a few lines of LaTeX that will keep track of this for me, but struggling a bit to get the wordcount incorporated as a variable to a math equation. Here's what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Figuring out AGU's absurd "Publication Unit" scheme:
\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge #1.tex> #1-words}%
  \input{#1-words}
}

\newcommand{\MyWordcount}{\quickwordcount{agujournaltemplate}}
\newcommand{\MyTestVar}{37} %for testing purposes

\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}


\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalfigures}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totaltables}
% \NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigures}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltables}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp


\title{AGU Wordcount Test}

\begin{document}

% \maketitle


There are approximately \MyWordcount words in this article. There are \TotalValue{totalfigures} figures, and \TotalValue{totaltables} tables. That means we have a total of \num[scientific-notation=false]{\fpeval{(1/500)*\MyWordcount+ \TotalValue{totalfigures} + \TotalValue{totaltables}}} publication units, out of a maximum of 25.

\end{document}
```

This does not compile. If I replace \MyWordcount with \MyTestVar in the equation, it does fine. Any tips for making the wordcount into a variable for this purpose?

Comment: "Longer papers are assessed an excess length fee" --> I would balance the fee and the time you need to invest in order to get your code running :).

Comment: I plan on re-using the code a lot. ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do they offer a web service (input: PDF, output: PU count) to test your implementation?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I presume there is an internal tool. If I come up with an elegant way of doing it I may suggest they add it to their LaTeX template.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid writing to files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}
\usepackage{catchfile}

% Figuring out AGU's absurd "Publication Unit" scheme:
\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \CatchFileEdef\MyWordcount{|"texcount -1 -sum -merge #1.tex"}{\endlinechar=-1 }%
}
\quickwordcount{\jobname}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalfigures}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totaltables}
% \NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigures}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltables}

\title{AGU Wordcount Test}

\begin{document}

% \maketitle

\begin{figure}
\caption{a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{a}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{a}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\caption{a}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{a}
\end{table}


There are approximately \MyWordcount\ words in this article. 
There are \TotalValue{totalfigures} figures, and \TotalValue{totaltables} tables.
That means we have a total of 
\num[scientific-notation=false]{%
  \fpeval{(1/500)*\MyWordcount+ \TotalValue{totalfigures} + \TotalValue{totaltables}}%
} 
publication units, out of a maximum of 25.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this isn't quite complete, but it's close. Thanks to [stianlybech on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/moe6fe/putting_document_word_count_into_an_equation/gu40uo4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) for helping me out here. This code translates the number of words into publication units, although I haven't had any luck getting them to add (maybe because xassoccnt and pgf don't play nicely together.) It's good enough for my current purposes, but if anyone can find a workable way to add the counters into a single number that'd be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalfigures}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totaltables}
% \NewTotalDocumentCounter{appendixchapters}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{figure}{totalfigures}
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{table}{totaltables}
% \usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp


% per reddit:
\def\wordcountfile#1#2{
  \immediate\write18{detex '#1.tex' |wc -w > '\jobname.wc'}

  \newread\wcinput
  \openin\wcinput=\jobname.wc

  % The group localizes the change to \endlinechar
  \begingroup
    \endlinechar=-1
    \read\wcinput to \localline

    % xdef to ensure result is visible outside the local scope
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #2\endcsname{\localline}
  \endgroup
  \closein\wcinput
}


\usepackage{pgf}

\def\calcns#1{%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision = 1}%
\pgfmathparse{#1/500}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\def\PU#1#2#3{%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision = 1}%
\pgfmathparse{#1/500+#2+#3}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{AGU Wordcount Test}

\begin{document}
\wordcountfile{agujournaltemplate}{wordcount}

\maketitle





There are approximately \wordcount{} words in this article, which amounts to \calcns{\wordcount} publication units. There are \TotalValue{totalfigures} figures, and \TotalValue{totaltables} tables, which amount to one each.

% That means we have a total of \PU{\wordcount}{\TotalValue{totalfigures}}{\TotalValue{totaltables}} publication units, out of a maximum of 25.

See, that didn't work. But this does: \PU{\wordcount}{1}{0}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get TeXcount to write the count to file as TeX code by using TeXcount templates. Here's an example where the template is included as TeXcount (`%TC:...`) instructions within the document:

```
\documentclass{article}

%TC:newtemplate
%TC:template \def\CountOfAllWords{{word+hword+oword}}\n
%TC:template \def\CountOfTextWords{{word}}\n
%TC:template \def\CountOfHeaderWords{{hword}}\n

\begin{document}

\section{Word count in macro variables}

This is the text that is counted.

%TC:ignore
\section{Word count}

\immediate\write18{texcount -merge -out=\jobname.count \jobname.tex}%
\input{\jobname.count}

There are \CountOfTextWords~words in the text, and \CountOfHeaderWords~words
in headers: all words add up to \CountOfAllWords.
The `Word count' section is not included in the count.
%TC:endignore

\end{document}
```

Instead of the regular summary output, now the template will be written with `{word}` and `{hword}` replaced with the text and header word counts. The different counters are: word/text, headerword, otherword, header, float, inlinemath, displaymath (with shorter aliases like hword, oword, etc available).

Additional documentation can be found on the [TeXcount web site](https://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/documentation.html) and the PDF documents linked to there, including how to add new counters.